# Comando SQL PARTITION BY?

Tags: sql

Estou lendo e não ficou muito claro o comando `PARTITION BY` na criação de tabelas no bancos de dados estruturados (`SQL`), ***um exemplo básico***:

```
CREATE TABLE employees  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL    
)   
PARTITION BY RANGE(id)  (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (15),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

***Pergunto:***

- Para que server de uma maneira geral o comando `PARTITION BY`?
- Quais a vantagens e desvantagens desse comando?

Comment: Tem algum problema a pergunta, ela não faz sentido, o que posso fazer para melhorar, já faz algum tempo que ando sendo perseguido e tomando votos negativos todos os dias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente o *PARTITION BY* cria uma tabela com uma ou mais partições; em outras palavras, são criadas tabelas físicas que serão acessadas através da tabela especificada.

Exemplificando, ao criar a tabela `imovel` e definir que ela deve ser particionada pela quantidade de quartos *pares* e *ímpares*, seriam criados no BD duas tabelas, *"imovelQuartosPares"* e *"imovelQuartosImpares"*, que seriam acessíveis através do `select * from tabelas`.

Esse particionamento pode ser controlado de várias formas, serão mostrados apenas dois para ajudar no entendimento, mas uma lista com as possibilidades e explicações pode ser encontrada [neste link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Partitioning):

**PARTITION BY LIST**

Pode ser usado quando a partição precisar ser feita baseada em valores definidos, por exemplo particionar a tabela `usuarios` pelo sexo:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios
( id NUMBER, nome VARCHAR2(50), idade NUMBER, sexo VARCHAR2(1))
PARTITION BY LIST (sexo) (
    PARTITION masculino VALUES ('M'),
    PARTITION feminino VALUES ('F')
);
```

**PARTITION BY RANGE**

Usado quando a partição precisar ser feita com base em intervalos, como por exemplo faixa etária:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios
( id NUMBER, nome VARCHAR2(50), idade NUMBER, sexo VARCHAR2(1))
PARTITION BY RANGE (idade) (
    PARTITION crianca VALUES LESS THAN (18),
    PARTITION adulto VALUES LESS THAN (65),
    PARTITION idoso VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

---

*Entendendo o exemplo da pergunta:*

```
CREATE TABLE employees  (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL    
)   
PARTITION BY RANGE(id)  (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (5),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (10),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (15),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Criada a tabela `employees` particionada em quatro outras tabelas:

- `p0` - registros com `id` menor que *5*;
- `p1` - registros com `id` maior ou igual a *5* e menor que *10*;
- `p1` - registros com `id` maior ou igual a *10* e menor que *15*;
- `p3` - registros com `id` maior ou igual a *15*.

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta, como seria a parte do SQL? ficaria a cargo do próprio banco pegar os dados das outras tabelas criadas?

Comment: como assim "a parte do SQL"? É preciso definir como será feita essa _divisão_, não ficará a cargo do sgbd (se é que entendi correto).

Comment: Talvez tenha expressando mau, exemplo `select * from tabela where code > 30` vamos dizer que o dado esteja nas tabelas auxiliares... ? tipo não preciso fazer nada o banco se encarregada de buscas as informações nos tabelas auxiliares?

Comment: _"seriam acessíveis através do `select * from tabelas`"_ - beleza, isso é responsabilidade do sgbd. No caso, a consulta seria escrita como você fez (`select * from tabela where code > 30`) sem precisar informar em qual partição pesquisar.

Answer (score 3):

Particionar uma tabela significa dividir uma tabela, que é logicamente grande, em várias tabelas fisicamente pequenas com o objetivo de melhorar o desempenho das aplicações que utilizam o banco de dados.
Por exemplo você pode particionar uma tabela de vendas em diversas tabelas cada uma referente a um ano-mês da venda, logicamente você tem todas as vendas mas fisicamente os acessos a cada ano-mês das vendas serão otimizados.